# How can I refresh a page (which is not my own) using C#?

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm making a Telegram (a messenger app) bot and I have a link which by using it I can send messages to a particular user.
How can I "refresh" that webpage in C# so it'd automatically send the link?

Comment: Do you just need to make an HTTP request in C# code?  The `HttpClient` object would be used for that.

Comment: Does the Telegram app have an API?   If so, it would be better to check its documentation for officially supported methods of doing this

Comment: This question is *way* too broad.  How is your C# program acting as a client to this webpage?  and what does refresh mean, exactly?

Comment: Thx @David pretty sure that's what I'm looking for, I just cannot find the right method.

Comment: By refresh I guess I mean a request, I wanna cause the same thing as pressing the refresh button in the browser. Sorry for the dumb wording.

Comment: Thx a lot, that's exactly what I needed, I looked it up everywhere but for some reason none of them worked. Maybe I tried the wrong one or didn't add a reference but this time it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question and comments thereof, it sounds like you're just asking how to make an HTTP request in C#.  If that's the case, the `HttpClient` makes pretty short work of that.  For example:

```
var url = "http://someurl";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
using (var content = response.Content)
{
    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // examine the response
}
```

If you don't even much care about the response then you can just make the call and abandon the response:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
    await client.GetAsync(url);
```

Or maybe keep the same `HttpClient` instance instead of wrapping it in a `using` block to dispose of it, etc.  The same object can also make `POST` or any other requests as needed, etc.